# converter projetos java para maven

Tags: java, maven, conversão

Tenho alguns projetos java e gostaria de converte-los pro maven.

- Existe algum comando `maven` para conversão de projetos java já existentes?
- Se eu simplesmente adicionar o `pom.xml` ele se tornará um projeto maven?

Pensei nesses dois casos pois não tenho o eclipse e gostaria de colocar esse processo num pipeline.

Comment: Nunca parei pra testar isso, mas acabei de testar aqui no NetBeans 12, peguei dois projetos um em HTML e outro JavaScript adicionei o Pom.xml neles a IDE reconheceu como projetos Maven.

Answer (score 1):

Não basta adicionar o `pom.xml`. É preciso que o projeto siga, pelo menos, a estrutura de diretórios:

```
- pom.xml
- src
  |-- main
  |   |-- java
  |   |   |-- App.java
  |   |-- resources
  |       |-- file.csv
  |-- test
      |-- java
      |   |-- AppTest.java
      |-- resources
          |-- testfile.csv
```

Há, evidentemente, outras possibilidades de organização dos diretórios e ficheiros de configuração adicionais, mas esta é a mínima para ele poder ser executado como projeto Maven.

Quanto a haver algum comando `maven` que faça, isso não sei.